# Reload data on change

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, reload

so I will try to be as clear as possible on my question!
On my site I have a table with the latest reservations, it's a fetch request that retrieves the data in PHP in JSON format and Javascript that puts them in shape, it works very well. But now I would like to go one step further, and make an automatic system, which would only have the Javascript function to retrieve and format the data. But I would need to do this without having to do a `setInterval()` or wait for the user's click, somehow only when a row is added (which is not done by the admin but the system the detect), the array is reloaded. I don't know at all if it's possible or not, and that's why I'm asking here?
(I only work in Javascript with Jquery and with PHP, I don't know if I need another lib?)
Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: I think you are looking for a web socket solution

Comment: With only Jquery and PHP there is only way to do it. You have to continuously send request to backend check if there is any change. If there is then return back and refresh table. For each 1-2 seconds. For more complex but better solution you can use socket as @CornelRaiu said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use websocket, you can get better system.
but, if you can't, I recommend you use setInterval() to check if the row added.

You can install websocket server with nodejs easily.
and you have to add send event from php to nodejs ( http ) when new row added in your PHP server.
and add javascript websocket client.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet websocket which is used for php

Comment: Oh thank you very much! I didn't know Websocket at all, I'll try to find out. Have a good day !